# Separating Open API Documentations

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have quite alot of models and operations in my new backend API that I wish to document.

I am currently making use of the Open API Documentation standard.

Now, it's kindda cubersome keeping all of the Spec files in one giant `swagger.yaml` file.

My question now is, is it possible for me to separate the documenation files into units so for example

All Operations for **Customers** go inside `customer.yaml`
All Operations for **Merchants** go insider `merchants.yaml`

And then merging `customer.yaml` and `merchants.yaml` into one giant `swagger.yaml` file that would be exported as the documentation file for the API

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could use [$ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) (look up "Remote Reference"). For example, you can break down your giant yaml-file into smaller files. Then you'll end up with a master file, where remote files are included.

Comment: Yea, that's what I am trying to do but it seems $ref doesn't accept an array of file paths. It accepts just a single file path which is kindda bizarre.

Comment: That is true, one cannot make lists of $ref. However, there might be a workaround, depending on what your're trying to do: you can reference every property of an object, or use references inside referenced objects. However maybe I don't understand the question completely? Maybe an example file would help?